# Download and save a file using Java

Tags: java

Let's say I have an URL, like something.domain/myfile.txt then I want to save this file, with that "Save File" dialog.

I tried my best to do it, but everytime I save the file using the dialog the file is not there.

An example or somewhere I can find information on this would help a lot!

```
        URL website = null;
                try {
                    website = new URL(<insert url here>);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ReadableByteChannel rbc = null;
                try {
                    rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("minecraft.jar"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                    if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(fileChooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                      File dir = fileChooser.getCurrentDirectory(); 
                      dir.mkdir();
                      //After this point is where I need help.
```

Comment: What "Save File dialog" are you talking about? There's no such feature built into the API; you need to design your own save dialog.

Comment: If you're talking about the standard Swing JFileChoose or AWT FileDialog, then those can only browse the file system. They don't browse the web.

Comment: Try saving the file without any dialog first. From there you should check APIs for graphical applications and call the former functionality from the dialog.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't want it to browse the web. I want it to browse system directories, and when one is chosen as save location, the file from the specified URL is saved there.

Comment: @Vulcan I tried to use a JFileChooser. It works fine, but when I click save file, no file is created.

Comment: @BrunoPaschoalinoto In that case, we definitely need to see your code in order to help you.

Comment: @MKroehnert I tried that and the file was successfully saved. But when I added the JFileChooser, no file was there.

Comment: @Vulcan I'll add code to the post.

Comment: Code added. I'm sorry if it's a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

I trust that this is what you're looking for:

```
if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(fileChooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
  File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
  // whatever you want to do with the file
  System.out.println("The file is "+file.getAbsolutePath());
  // fos = new FileOutputStream(file) ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that in your code you are trying to save/download the file before giving the user the option to chose the destination?

I would split the code into three different operations:

1. A method in charge of transferring the bytes from the `InputStream` (the web) to the `OutputStream` (the file).
2. a method to show the user a dialog so he can chose where to store the file.
3. the method that completes the whole task: choose a file and transfer the bytes from the web to it.

1) Would be something like this (you don't need to use the NIO API to implement it):

```
public void transfer(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
   int bytesRead;
   while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }
}
```

2) would be something very similar to what Dukeling has already stated:

```
public File chooseFile() {
  File result = null;
  JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(fileChooser) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    result = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
  }
  return result;
}
```

3) then, combining these two operations together is really simple:

```
public void saveFileFromWeb(URL url) {
  File file = chooseFile();   // 1. Choose the destination file
  if (file != null) {
    // 2. Create parent folder structure
    File folder = file.getParentFile();
    if (!folder.exist()) {
       folder.mkdirs();
    }

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
      // 3. Initialise streams
      in = url.openStream();
      out = new FileOuputStream(file);
      // 4. Transfer data
      transfer(in, out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // 5. close streams
      if (in != null) {
        try {
          in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { /* ignore */ }
      }
      if (out != null) {
        try {
          out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { /* ignore */ }
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: 1) and 2) could be private methods. Of course you could do this is just one single operation but splitting it would give you an overview of the different steps to perform.

**NOTE 2**: I simplified the exception handling part